# Iterate over columns of a report to dynamically show/hide them?

Tags: loops, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I want to try and implement a parameter which will allow users to dynamically choose which columns are going to be shown in a report. An idea is to create a multiple value parameter which has column names. After user hit View Report I want to try iterate over columns and selected values to join visibility.

How I can iterate over columns inside a tablix?

How I can iterate over multiple values of a parameter, so I can find if some value is selected or not?

I am using MS SQL Reporting Services 2012.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a table, i.e. fixed columns, you can use the following approach. It's not really loop based so much as an individual distinct visibility check for each column based on a parameter selection.

Set up a multi-valued parameter that lists the columns that can be displayed/hidden.

Then, for each of these columns in the actual table, set the **Column Visibility** to use an expression based on the parameter:

[image]

The expression would something like:

```
=IIf(InStr(Join(Parameters!IncludedColumn.Value, ","), "Col1") > 0, false, true)
```

What this is doing is constructing a string of all selected values for the *IncludedColumn* parameter, then checking if a certain column identifier is included; *Col1* for this particular column. You'd use different constants for each column.

So when running the report this approach can hide/display columns based on a parameter selection.

All columns selected:

[image]

Some columns selected:

[image]