# Hide a report column in SSRS

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have a web SSRS (2008) report that has many columns (about 20). I would like to know if it is possible to allow the user to show/hide a particular column in the report by clicking some button or checkbox or the like? The purpose of this would be to allow the user to see the columns they want to see.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372103/iterate-over-columns-of-a-report-to-dynamically-show-hide-them/16374555

Answer (score 2):

Right mouse click on the column and select "Visibility" property:

[image: SSRS Column Visibility]

One of the options "Display can be toggled by this report item" - you can point to a dedicated, formatted textbox, clicking on which would show/hide column

Comment: Hi @Yuriy Galanter, thanks, your solution is basically what I was looking for. Please see my screenshot I added to my original post. As you see, the only way to hide a column is to click the actual "+" box. Is it possible to make the clicking of the text itself hide the column? How about removing the "+" box altogether, as well as adding a "Reset" type button where it restores the reports columns to what they originally were?

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible with pure SSRS methods, too much interactivity for a medium designed to be printed or exported. Probably something would be possible with external help (e.g. JavaScript if report is displayed on a Web Page) but maybe you should consider something like a grid control instead.